# Making TileOverlays transparent

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm currently working on a App that uses a custom TileSource to display data on Google Maps. I get those data in form of *.png images, and I'm using the URLTileProvider.

Everything is working well, but I'm now trying to make the TileLayer transparent, or at least, partly. The goal is, that the layer is visible but the underlying Google Maps still shines through. Somehow I'm stuck, as I do not know how to achieve this.

- I did not find a way to fully implement a custom TileProvider, it seems one can only extend URLTileProvider
- Serverside imagemanipulation is not possible, as the data is given
- There are no options to make a TileOverlay transparent? (alpha, opacity, transparency)

I'd be very helpful if someone could hint me in the right direction, or tell me whether the Google Maps API V2 for Android really does not support this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this moment it is not possible to specify transparency for TileOverlay in android maps sdk v2.
Unfortunately `setTransparency(float)` method is available for `GroundOverlay` only..  The only way to do this - is to implement your own TileProvider and change png 'on-the-fly' to change alpha channel.

Comment: This is the way I did it in the end: I created my own custom TileProvider that fetchted the Tile via a Inputstream from the URL, then generated a bitmap via `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` for modification with this function:  
`private Bitmap adjustOpacity(Bitmap bitmap)`  
Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;  
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 256, conf);  
  
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);  
Paint paint = new Paint();  
paint.setAlpha(tileOpacity);  
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);  
  
return bmp;  
}

Comment: I have a similar problem Elysium and I also have my own TileProvider. But I find that I can't change the transparency of the tile after it's been drawn.  Do you use your "adjustOpacity" any time after it's been drawn?

Comment: Did you convert the Bitmap back to a byte[] after adjusting the opacity?  Otherwise, how did you create a Tile from a Bitmap to be returned by getTile()?  Thanks.

Comment: @paul, yes, you need to convert your bitmap back to byte array when you are done

Comment: I wrote a custom TileProvider that uses @Elysium's adjustOpacity() method and does all this for us. Just pop in the custom TileProvider instead of the URLTileProvider, set your opacity (if desired is different than 75%), and you're all set. Check it out here: http://blog.awnry.com/post/88749232734/changing-tileoverlay-opacity-for-androids-google-maps

Comment: Transparency is working as tested currently as mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(new CustomMapTileProvider(getResources().getAssets())).transparency(0.5f));

Answer (score 2):

Can you make the tile images themselves transparent?  The URLTileProvider can point to any images so if the image has alpha, it should work.

You can implement a TileProvider directly but you will have to take care of loading your own image data in that case.  It seems like that would be more desirable if you want to generate tiles dynamically on the client.